# Where to ask a question about accessing xlsm files

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've got an .xlsm file that I'd like to ask the following question about:

> How to view the source, or worksheets, in an xlsm?

Where would be the most appropriate place for this?

Comment: SuperUser seems right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like that's spot on for [Super User](http://superuser.com). Specifically the [Microsoft Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) tag.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just wanted to ensure I got the right place.